# How do I convert a 2d array into a 1d array of strings?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a 2d array of the following form:

```
[  [(,  (,  (,  (,  (,],
   [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,], 
   [+,  +,  +,  +,  +,],
   [2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,],
   [),  ),  ),  ),  )] 

]
```

i.e a mixture of integers and mathematical characters. What I want to do is convert this into a series of strings in a 1D array like:

[
  (1+2),
  (1+2),
  (1+2),
  (1+2),
  (1+2) 
]

Is there a way to do this with join?

Comment: please, on questions provide valid Ruby objects, those strings are not strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-transpose), and then join the elements of the transposed array (I have modified the numbers to clearly show what is happening):

```
# edited to add a transpose with map, thank you @Mladen
# edited to get rid of <<'s, thank you @tokland

# assumption: 
a = [ ['(', '(', '(', '(', '('],
      [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5],
      ['+', '+', '+', '+', '+'],
      [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5],
      [')', ')', ')', ')', ')'] ]

# transpose:
b = []
a.transpose.each { |c| b.push c.join }

# or, transpose with map:
b = a.transpose.map { |c| c.join }

# test:
puts b.inspect
```

Which has as an output:

```
["(1.1+2.1)", "(1.2+2.2)", "(1.3+2.3)", "(1.4+2.4)", "(1.5+2.5)"]
```

Comment: of course! transpose, since we don't have Array.zip, it's the way to go, I'll update my answer. Try to write without << or each and magically you'll be writing functional code ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
xs.transpose.map(&:join)
#=> ["(1.1+2.1)", "(1.2+2.2)", "(1.3+2.3)", "(1.4+2.4)", "(1.5+2.5)"]
```

(side note: if you want to know why we can't write `Array.zip(*xs)` look at this [issue](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6499). [Facets guys did implement it](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/commit/7cd2234776a98e8cd12432cbcf21f9ed3ee9a9c4).)